# Using delayed_job on a non-ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, undefined, delayed-job

I'm attempting to use `handle_asynchronously` on a method of a class, as per the following:

```
class MyClass
  def publish_stream(opts={})
    # . . .
  end
  handle_asynchronously :publish_stream
end
```

When delayed_job attempts to execute, it throws the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `publish_stream_without_send_later' for #<YAML::Object:0xbb52b00>
```

(Note that the  I replaced the actual method name with "my_method" above.)

I believe the exception is occurring because the class defining this method is not derived from `ActiveRecord::Base`; instead, it's simply derived from `Object`.  What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, it turns out that the delayed_job rake task must be loading something in the wrong order.  It worked fine in the console.  The solution was to do the following manually in an initializer:

```
require 'my_class'
```

where "my_class" is the filename of the class.

Answer (score 1):

My **guess** is that DelayedJob tries to serialize the object you are working on, and it cannot recreate the object from that.

Comment: Not sure who marked your answer down, but it wasn't me.  It looks like this might be the case, and I'm still digging into it.  Thanks for the response!